# Django/JQuery.ajax. Get values from JSON using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

My view looks like this:

```
def change(request):
    users = Account.objects.all().to_json()
    return HttpResponse(users, mimetype='application/json')
```

And my javascript in my template looks like this:

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/change/',
    type: 'get', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      alert(data.username)
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
  });
```

I can see in the firebug console that server's response looks ok:

```
[{"username": "admin", "project_list": [], "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$OA1nceoBeMj2$XFZfZdfOpd7LKOGKyHrnVPUv89daY8+RzoAhApI+ePs=", "is_active": true, "is_superuser": true, "is_staff": false, "last_login": {"$date": 1420983256456}, "_cls": "User.Account", "groups": [], "user_permissions": [], "role": "admin", "_id": {"$oid": "54b27bca8a8d5114ee764bd7"}, "date_joined": {"$date": 1420983242745}}]
```

But when i try to print anything in alert using

```
alert(data)
```

or

```
alert(data.field)
```

for example field = username i get undefined.
When i use alert(data) it just says it's an object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$.each()` iterator:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    console.log(item.username);
});
```

Because you get an `[{}, {}]` array of js objects, so if you directly access the key name to get the respective value you can't get it. so instead you have to loop in it to have the access to the objects.

So in the code above `item` is the current js object and `item.username` will log `admin`.

Comment: It works fine with the $.each iterator. Thanks!
Are there no other options?